# Delete entire column when data type is ""

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I want to delete entire empty column using a VBA code. But it include invisible data pasted from "".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test a column (say column **A**) to see if it contains only empty cells and *Nulls*, in the worksheet you would use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(A:A)>0))
```

and make sure the formula returns ***0***.  In VBA:

```
Sub KolumnTest()
    Dim n As Long
    n = Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(A:A)>0))")
    If n = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Column A contains only empties and nulls"
    Else
        MsgBox "Column A is not empty and should not be deleted"
    End If
End Sub
```